# Building and run go scripts on Apache under fcgi

Tags: apache, go, fastcgi

For run every script i do:

```
go build script.go
mv script script.fcgi
```

My apache config looks so:

```
<VirtualHost [myip]:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName website.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/www
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /our_bin [QSA,L]
    <Directory /home/user/www>
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Question:
1) If i build 1 script, it will builded with all packages that i link, right?
2) How i can customize fcgi and go so that it will not need build every time

sorry for bad english

Comment: You can't. Go isn't a " scripting language" and Apache doesn't know how to process it (unlike PHP FCGI and variants). You need to build (compile) your Go application with a HTTP or FCGI server, and run it, and then use Apache (or nginx) to reverse proxy to the HTTP port/FCGI socket your Go app is listening on.

Comment: @elithrar Post that as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Go isn't a "scripting language" and Apache doesn't know how to process it (unlike PHP FCGI and variants).

You need to build (compile) your Go application with a HTTP or FCGI server, and run it, and then use Apache (or nginx) to reverse proxy to the HTTP port/FCGI socket your Go app is listening on.

Take a look at the [net/http](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) documentation and the [simple web application](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) tutorial in the Go documentation. From my experience I'd recommend using a reverse HTTP proxy over FCGI as it's easier to debug/configure.

i.e.

```
<VirtualHost myhost:80>
                ServerName www.mydomain.com
                ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/ # Your Go app's listening port
                ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that this isn't tested nor a complete example, but should hopefully get you started.